# No exception thrown from boost::asio::ip::address::from_string on invalid address

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Does anybody know why:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::ip::address const addr =
   boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.10.10", ec);
```

does not return error, since 10.10.10 is invalid address ?

Instead of this 10.10.10 is modified to 10.10.0.10 in addr and no exception is thrown ?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question at all, but according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address.html the `from_string()` function is deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`boost::asio::ip::address::from_string()` relies on `inet_pton()` internally which accepts things like 10.10.10 as valid addresses. The string "10.10" is used for the two top octets. The remaining "10" is interpreted as 16-bit number and splitted across the last two octets.
Altogether this gets correctly interpreted into 10.10.0.10 .

Besides, your call `boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.10.10", ec);` does not throw since it uses `boost::system::error_code`.

Comment: Heh, I dug down as far as [`inet_pton`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/a57cb2a7a6721ed25fa7cfaa577ae1a985fc31f7/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L2133), then the size of the function with many different platform-specific implementations scared me into doing some real work instead. Is the behaviour you describe intentionally useful, or a strange implementation side-effect?

Comment: As far as I can remember the idea behind this is to simplify the usage when dealing with IP ranges / incrementing IPs. Imagine incrementally going from 192.168.0 ... 192.168.255 which actually results in the range 192.168.0.0 ... 192.168.0.255 . The next incremental value would be 192.168.256 which results in 192.168.1.0 .

Answer (score 1):

Boost provide two type of variant for(Atlest which I uses) all function

1. Which can two exception. This type of function doesn't have argument of type `boost::system::error_code`.
2. Which shouldn't throw exception but instead it set parameter of type `boost::system::error_code` as argument accordingly.

Have look at https://wandbox.org/permlink/0wXerng3CYzhAOtT